# Javascript sum of elements value

Tags: javascript

javascript code:

```
function getCheckbox(name,id){
  var check = 0; 
  var deger = "option-checkbox-"+id; 
  var dom = document.getElementById(deger); 
  if( dom.checked )
       check += parseFloat( dom.value ); 
  else check -= parseFloat( dom.value ); 
  return check.toFixed(2);**//right value.(12.45)** 
} 

function getRadio(name,id) {
  var radio=0; 
  var deger="option-radio-"+id; 
  var radio="option["+name+"]"; 
  var selectedli = document.getElementsByName(radio); 
  var degerli    = document.getElementById(deger); 
  if( selectedli.checked )
       radio = parseFloat( degerli.value );
  else radio = parseFloat( degerli.value )
  return radio.toFixed(2)**//right value.(42.00)** 
} 

function getSelected(name,id) {
  var selectedid="option["+name+"]"; 
  var selecte = 0; 
  var selected = document.getElementById( selectedid ); 
  selecte = parseFloat(selected.value); 
  return selecte.toFixed(2);**//right value.(-12.29)** 
} 

function toplam(name,id) {**//not expected(0)** 
  var toplan = 0; 
  toplan = getSelected(name,id)+getRadio(name,id)+getCheckbox(name,id); 
  $( '#toplam_goster' ).fadeOut(200, function(){
    document.getElementById("toplam_goster").innerHTML = toplan;
  }); 
  $( '#toplam_goster' ).fadeIn(200); 
}
```

.In the last function return 0. How can I fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demo reproducing the problem?

Comment: your last function don't have a return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> return selecte.toFixed(2); // this returns string and addition might
>   return 0

either return number, i.e. return selecte*1
or convert to number before adding, i.e.

```
toplan=getSelected(name,id)*1+getRadio(name,id)*1+getCheckbox(name,id)*1;
```

Comment: Even with it returning strings, using the `+` operator would result in string concatenation. If the values being returned are as he states (I have doubts about this because the code doesn't look like it would even run successfully) then the result shouldn't be `0`. It is a valid point, however, and will cause him problems later on once he's fixed the other issues with the code.

Comment: not always - it will return 0 (zero) if concatenation is evaluated to false

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with this particular function:

```
function getRadio(name,id) 
{      
    var radio=0; 
    var deger="option-radio-"+id; 
    var radio="option["+name+"]"; 
    var selectedli = document.getElementsByName(radio); 
    var degerli =document.getElementById(deger); 
    if(selectedli.checked) {
        radio = parseFloat(degerli.value);
    }
    else {
        radio = parseFloat(degerli.value)
    } 
    return radio.toFixed(2)**//right value.(42.00)** 
}
```

You're declaring the `radio` variable twice - originally with a value of `0` and then as a string.

You're calling `document.getElementsByName()` which returns an array of elements, then later on doing `selectedli.checked`; the array won't have a checked property. If you're expecting it to only return a single `radio` element, you should be testing `selectedli[0].checked`.

You have an `if` statement that executes the same code regardless of whether the condition evaluates to true. This is either a mistake on your part or the `if` statement can be done away with entirely.